# Why is my data not added to the heroku sandbox database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I created a node/React App, which I deployed to heroku. When I post data in my local env, the data is added to the database. However, when I attempt to post data in production, the data is not added to the db.I'm using the mLab mongodb sandbox

Here is my db setup
Local Env Variables:

`MONGODB_URI = mongodb://localhost/ptwd-server`

Production Env Variables

`MONGODB_URI = mongodb://heroku_l355djmk:nc4250agdig7a9sbjtkhht15e3@ds261238.mlab.com:61238/heroku_l355djmk`

```
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true})
  .then(x => console.log(`Connected to Mongo! Database name: "${x.connections[0].name}"`))
  .catch(err => console.error('Error connecting to mongo', err));
```

Edit to add heroku logs

```
2020-01-07T16:27:57.401551+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/2.65d0fb23.chunk.js.map" host=minacre8s.herokuapp.com request_id=b9ec673d-9f89-45be-84c0-ad99c2646539 fwd="146.168.124.114" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=188ms status=200 bytes=10034234 protocol=http
2020-01-07T16:28:20.191539+00:00 app[web.1]: OPTIONS /signup 204 0.991 ms - 0
2020-01-07T16:28:20.357966+00:00 app[web.1]: POST /signup 200 30.189 ms - 2673
2020-01-07T16:28:20.424986+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /images/signup.jpg 200 2.984 ms - 526016
2020-01-07T16:28:20.191668+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/signup" host=minacre8s.herokuapp.com request_id=197ae6a1-81d3-4492-b6f3-662f1fe992c9 fwd="146.168.124.114" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=204 bytes=378 protocol=https
2020-01-07T16:28:20.352452+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/signup" host=minacre8s.herokuapp.com request_id=5701c84b-4c43-4b39-be52-b74a70f8b34c fwd="146.168.124.114" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=36ms status=200 bytes=3077 protocol=https
2020-01-07T16:28:20.441878+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/signup.jpg" host=minacre8s.herokuapp.com request_id=496fe7da-3309-4018-9c3d-4291eb407064 fwd="146.168.124.114" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=29ms status=200 bytes=526295 protocol=http
```

**Post Route:**

```
  const { firstName, lastName, email, password } = req.body;

  if(firstName == "" || lastName == "" || email == "" || password.match(/[0-9]/) === null){
    // send JSON file to the frontend if any of these fields are empty or password doesn't contain a number
    res.status(401).json({ message: "All fields need to be filled and password must contain a number! "});
    return;
  }

  User
    .findOne({ email })
    .then( foundUser => {
      if(foundUser !== null ){
        res.status(401).json({ message: "A user with the same email is already registered!" });
        return;
      }

      const bcryptSalt = 10;
      const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(bcryptSalt);
      const encryptedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);

      User
        .create({ firstName, lastName, email, encryptedPassword })
        .then( userDoc => { 
          // if all good, log in the user automatically
          // "req.login()" is a Passport method that calls "serializeUser()"
          // (that saves the USER ID in the session)

          // req.login(userDoc, (err) => {
          //   if(err){
          //     res.status(401).json({ message: "Something happened when logging in after the signup" });
          //     return;
          //   }
          //   userDoc.encryptedPassword = undefined;
          res.status(200).json({ userDoc });  
          console.log(`added user, ${userDoc}`)
          // })
         } )
        .catch( err => next(err) ); // close User.create()
    })
    .catch(err => next(err)); // close User.findOne()
});
```

Comment: Are you able to connect to your production mongo successfully? (e.g. do you receive "Connected to Mongo" message. Also, can you edit your post to show how you are trying to save data?

Comment: No. I'm not getting the connected to Mongo in the heroku logs.

Comment: To confirm, this runs fine when you replace process.env.MONGODB_URI with local host?

Comment: yes, all of my data post to the db in my local env. I have local host in my .env file, MONGODB_URI = mongodb://localhost/ptwd-server.

Comment: Can you try running the app again, then running "heroku logs" via command line? Either success or error should be recorded given your code.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was able to fix my issue by adding a store to my session using the connect-mongo npm package.